# What are the events triggered by the standard Opportunity Sales Path?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events, salespath

I want to build some functionality that will notify the user once they click on any stage in the standard sales path on the opportunity layout but before record save. What are the events which I can listen to and handle in order to invoke my lwc?

Comment: Sales Path can be configured for many objects in your org. Typically the Opportunity Sales Path will use Stage or Status as the driving picklist. The event in this case would be "OnChange of Opportunity Stage or Status", invoke LWC. Note, if the Page Layout exposes these fields to Users, your LWC can then be invoked away from the Sales Path also.

Comment: @TSmith, Can you pls elaborate on the "OnChange of Opportunity Stage or Status" event? Is this a standard event?

Answer (score 1):

I have researched your issue and found out you can use a standard JS library called MutationObserver.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

It looks for any change across the DOM and triggers an event you can initialize in connectedCallBack with an event handler.

There you can check if the SalesPath is changing or not you need to add a few conditions to check if the changes happening are from SalesPath or not.

If you found out the changes are from SalesPath then you can just execute your logic on it.

I hope it will help you out otherwise feel free to ask for help.

Comment: No, I am looking at ways to call a lwc on click of stage on the sales path. This is before a DML

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: Great, this looks promising. Thanks!